# Categorize duplicate elements under same key

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have this list:

```
public class Connection
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }
}

List<Connection> connectionsList;
```

I want to get all the `Name` from the list that are sharing the same `IP`.
I've tried:

```
    var duplicateIPConnections =
        connectionsList.GroupBy(x => x.IP)
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .SelectMany(g => g);
```

But the result is an enumerable with all the elements appearing after each other.
What I want is that the elements will be sorted **under** the `IP` that they both sharing.

Comment: It looks like you almost there. You don't need selectmany unless you need a flat list. That way all Connection will be grouped under ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   var duplicateIPConnections = connectionsList.OrderBy(x => x.IP)
                   .GroupBy(x => x.IP)
                   .Select(g => new
                   {
                       Type = g.Key,
                       Sites = g.Select(obj => new
                       {
                           obj.IP,
                           obj.Name
                       })
                   });
```